# Best Practices For "Nullable" Checkboxes

Tags: picklist, checkbox

I'm managing an org where a bunch of new checkbox fields are going to be added - they are optional and it is important to know if the checkbox was actively being checked or not checked by the user. So, obviously, a checkbox cannot do this in Salesforce as it is not nullable. Now I wonder - what are my options for working around this? Are there any best practices?

The current idea is to have a picklist that can be empty and has only two values: true & false. This is more cumbersome for the user but at least we get the information that we need. Are the any different "hacks" to resolve this? And - on a related note - is Salesforce ever going to change this?

Answer (score 0):

The picklist idea is at this point the most viable solution, you could however add to this by providing a flow or LWC to the user where an actual checkbox can be used and set to null and you relay this information back to the correct picklist field, essentially "hiding" the picklist and showing a nullable checkbox.

the LWC could be added to parts of the page looking something like this:

[ ] My checkbox [empty]

[ ] My 2nd checkbox [empty]

[ ] My 3rd checkbox [empty]

etc...

making the [empty] part into a button where the user can "nullify" the picklist.